# Make string move to next line on GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have a GridView and in one of the columns it displays a list of names.
This list can get long so it causes the GridView to get very long and it cuts off the names. I then have to go to the bottom of the grid and scroll across.

[image]

Is there a way to put a break into the Grid so after 5 names it will make the names go to the next line? This line comes from some SQL code that concats all the names into a string:

```
(SELECT CAST(group_concat(CONCAT(cc.username)separator ',') AS CHAR(200)) FROM message
```

Code for GridView:

```
public static GridView BuildUserChatsGrid()
        {
            GridView NewDg = new GridView();

            NewDg.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "ID" };
            NewDg.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            NewDg.CssClass = "tblResults draggable";
            NewDg.HeaderStyle.CssClass = "tblResultsHeader";
            NewDg.AlternatingRowStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyleAlt";
            NewDg.RowStyle.CssClass = "ResultsStyle";
            NewDg.RowDataBound += ChatsGridDataBound;

            NewDg.Columns.Add(new BoundField { DataField = "SentDate", HeaderText = "Date/Time" });
            NewDg.Columns.Add(new BoundField { DataField = "MembersIncluded", HeaderText = "Members Included" });

            NewDg.Width = Unit.Percentage(100.00);

            return NewDg;
        }
```

Comment: There is a property called `TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"` that will allow you to control that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixing the column width would force the text to wrap. You can set the value of `ItemStyle.Width` in pixels:

```
new BoundField { DataField = "FieldName", ItemStyle = { Width = Unit.Pixel(200) } }
```

or in percentage:

```
new BoundField { DataField = "FieldName", ItemStyle = { Width = Unit.Percentage(40) } }
```

or in another of the available units.

Please note that text wrapping will take place only if there are spaces in the text. You would have to use `', '` instead of `','` in the string concatenation of the SELECT query.

Comment: Using `ItemStyle ` didn't work. The names still show in one long line

Comment: Oh, you are right. It is because there is no space between the names. Would it be acceptable for you to separate the names with `', '` instead of `','`?

Answer (score 0):

Add the ItemStyle.Wrap setting as follows:

```
new BoundField {DataField="FieldName", ItemStyle = {Width = Unit.Pixel(200), Wrap = true}};
```

UPDATE: As @ConnorsFan suggested, the Wrap=true will have no effect. However, I'd suggest to try also specifying the CssStyle for the BoundField and defining the "max-width: 200px;" for that style.

Comment: Setting `Wrap = true` explicitely is the same as not specifying the property in the constructor. The default value for the `Wrap` property is `true`.